# How to print red pixels

Tags: java

I am trying to print a completely red box. Although, I am trying to do it by printing red pixels, not by printing the four corners of the square. Right now it only prints a red line.

```
import images.APImage;
import images.Pixel;

public class Square {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        APImage image = new APImage(400, 400);

        for (Pixel p : image){
            p.setRed(255);
            p.setGreen(0);
            p.setBlue(0);
            image.draw();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know with library you are using or anything your are doing at all.
But my feeling says your code should look more like this:

```
import images.APImage;
import images.Pixel;
public class Square{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        APImage image = new APImage(400, 400);

        for (Pixel p : image){
            p.setRed(0);
            p.setGreen(255);
            p.setBlue(0);
        }
        image.draw();
    }
}
```

I think you should give more detail and context.